# How to create Stub for Titanium Appcelerator?

Tags: iphone, ios, titanium

How to generate WSDL to Client Stub for web Service in Titanium.

I have generated for Objective-C, using WSDL2Obj tool which create stub for Objective-C language.

Is there any  Client stub generator for Titanium?  or do I need to hard-code the web services call?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working a lot with Titanium but i **never heard of a client stub generator for Titanium**.

Since Titanium is 'advanced' JavaScript you could try to create a simple JavaScript stub and modify the request calls. But this might be some work because structure of JavaScript's `XMLHttpRequest` and Titaniums's `Ti.Network.HTTPClient` is really different in creation (constructor). The other methods (onload, onerror,...) are similar but also not equal.

In all the apps we made we had a fix implementation of our web service although we have our own stub generator for REST clients. But this wouldn't work well with JavaScript.